# code running perfectly fine in clion, 10 errors generated in the terminal

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors, clion

I'm new to c++ and as I'm currently learning, I'm getting myself familiar with the syntax and everything else so I created many functions that do very basic stuff and included them in `main.cpp` that is created by default in clion IDE. All of the functions are tested separately under `main()` and all of them work perfectly fine. However, when I try copy and pasting the code in a separate file that let's say I name `examples.cpp` as far as I know here's how I run it separately in the terminal(mac os):

```
make examples
./examples
```

and it should create the executable file and run or at least that's what I'm expecting.
Here's how `main.cpp` which I rename to a separate file outside clion project folder called `examples.cpp` looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;


int no_val(){
    int age = 5;
    cout << age << endl;
    return 0;
}


double calculate_area(double width, double length){
    return width * length;
}


double calculate_area_inputs(){
    double width;
    double length;
    cout << "Enter room width: ";
    cin >> width;
    cout << "\nEnter room length: ";
    cin >> length;
    return width * length;
}


void signed_unsigned(){
    int x1 = -23;
    unsigned x2 = -55;
    cout << x1 << " " << x2 << endl;
}


long double types(){
    short int x1 = 10000;
    long double x2 = 1'000'000;
    long double x3 = 5e300;
    short product = 5 * 5;
    return product;
}


void sizes(){
    cout << "char: " << sizeof(char) << endl;
    cout << "string: " << sizeof(string) << endl;
    cout << "int: " << sizeof(int) << endl;
    cout << "float: " << sizeof(float) << endl;
    cout << "double: " << sizeof(double) << endl;
    cout << "short int: " << sizeof(short int) << endl;
    cout << "long int: " << sizeof(long int) << endl;
    cout << "long double: " << sizeof(long double) << endl;
    cout << "const int: " << sizeof(const int) << endl;

}

void other_syntax(){
    int x1 = 12U;
    int x2 = 15L;
    int x3 = 155UL;
    const int x4 = 1555LL;
}

void containers(){
    int abc [5];
    int xyz [5] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    vector<int> aaa;
    vector<vector<int>> bbb {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10}};
}

void statements(){
    int a = 6;
    int b = 5;
    if (a > b) cout << "a > b";
};

void control(int z){
    if (z > 10){
        cout << z;
        cout << "\n" << z * 10;
    }
    else {
        cout << "XYZ" << endl;
    }
}

void more_control(){
    enum Color{
        red, green, blue
    };
    Color screen_color {red};
    switch (screen_color) {
        case red: cout << "red"; break;
        case green: cout << "green"; break;
        case blue: cout << "blue"; break;
        default: "shouldn't execute";
    }
}

void more_control_2(){
    char expected_grade;
    cout << "What grade do you expect? ";
    cin >> expected_grade;
    switch (expected_grade) {
        case 'a': cout << "90 - 100";
            break;
        case 'b': cout << "80 - 90";
            break;
        case 'c': cout << "70 - 80";
            break;
        case 'd': cout << "60 - 60";
            break;
        default: cout << "Fail";
    }
}

int conditions(int n){
    return (n > 5) ? 23 : 55;
}

void initialize_vector(long int n){
    time_t t1, t2;
    time(&t1);
    vector<int> nums(n);
    time(&t2);
    double duration = difftime(t2, t1);
    printf ("time taken for function() %.2lf seconds.\n", duration);
}

void initialize_array(long int n){
    int nums [n];
    cout << "array: " << sizeof(nums) / sizeof(nums[0]) << endl;
}

void loops() {
    for (int i = 0, j = 100; i <= 100, j >= 0; ++i, --j)
        cout << "(" << i << ", " << j << ") ";
    cout << endl;
    int scores [] {30, 22, 40, 29, 5};
    for (auto score: scores)
        cout << score << " ";
    cout << endl;
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 10){
        cout << i << " ";
        ++i;
    }
    cout << endl;
    do {
        cout << i << " ";
        ++i;
    } while(i <= 20);
}

void strings(){
    char xyz [] {"xyz"};
    char xyz2 [] {"akj"};
    xyz2[3] = 'p';
    for (auto i: xyz2)
        cout << i;
    cout << endl;
    char xyx [8];
    strcpy(xyx, "jansasf");
    for (auto i: xyx)
        cout << i;
    cout << endl;
    char xyx2 [20];
    strcpy(xyx2, "klm");
    strcpy(xyx2, "zef");
    strcat(xyx2, "jefomok");
    for (auto i: xyx2)
        cout << i;
}

void more_strings(){
    char s1 [10];
    for (auto i: s1)
        cout << i;
    char aaa [] = {"kkklllmmm"};
    cout << aaa << endl;
    cout << "aaa is of length: " << strlen(aaa) << endl;
    string s2;
    string s3 {"abcd"};
    string s4 {"abcde", 2};
    string s5 {3, 'X'};
    cout << s2 << endl;
    cout << s3 << endl;
    cout << s4 << endl;
    cout << s5 << endl;
}

void more_strings2(){
    string pt1 {"xyx"};
    string pt2 {" kkk"};
    string sentence = pt1 + pt2;
    cout << sentence << endl;
    for (auto i: sentence)
        cout << i << " ";
    cout << endl;
    cout << sentence.substr(4, 8) << endl;
    cout << sentence.size() << endl;
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    string pt3;
    getline(cin, pt3);
    cout << pt3 << endl;
    cout << "Enter name again: ";
    string pt4;
    getline(cin, pt4, 'a');
    cout << pt4 << endl;
}

void mathematics(){
    cout << "RAND_MAX on my system is: " << RAND_MAX << endl;
}

void xxx(int abc = 5){
    cout << abc;
}

long double factorial(int n){
    if (n == 1 || n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * factorial(n - 1);

}

int add_numbers(int n1, int n2){
    return n1 + n2;
}

double add_numbers(double n1, double n2){
    return n1 + n2;
}

void print_array(const int xxx [], size_t size) {
    cout << '[';
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= size; ++i)
        cout << xxx[i] << ((i < size) ? " " : "");
    cout << ']';
}

void swap_values(int &a, int &b){
    int temp = a;
    a = b; b = temp;
}

void static_example()
{
    // static variable
    static int count = 0;
    cout << count << " ";

    // value is updated and
    // will be carried to next
    // function calls
    count++;
}

inline int add_nums(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}


int main() {
    cout << add_nums(1, 5);
    return 0;
}

void forward_declaration(int n){
    cout << "OK: " << n;
}
```

The following errors and warnings occur:

```
c++     examples.cpp   -o examples
examples.cpp:44:23: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    long double x2 = 1'000'000;
                      ^
                      ;
examples.cpp:73:16: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    int xyz [5] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
               ^
               ;
examples.cpp:75:22: error: a space is required between consecutive right angle
      brackets (use '> >')
    vector<vector<int>> bbb {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10}};
                     ^~
                     > >
examples.cpp:75:28: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    vector<vector<int>> bbb {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10}};
                           ^
                           ;
examples.cpp:98:23: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    Color screen_color {red};
                      ^
                      ;
examples.cpp:103:18: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        default: "shouldn't execute";
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
examples.cpp:143:32: warning: relational comparison result unused
      [-Wunused-comparison]
    for (int i = 0, j = 100; i <= 100, j >= 0; ++i, --j)
                             ~~^~~~~~
examples.cpp:146:9: error: definition of variable with array type needs an
      explicit size or an initializer
    int scores [] {30, 22, 40, 29, 5};
        ^
examples.cpp:146:18: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    int scores [] {30, 22, 40, 29, 5};
                 ^
                 ;
examples.cpp:147:10: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (auto score: scores)
         ^
examples.cpp:147:20: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (auto score: scores)
                   ^
examples.cpp:163:10: error: definition of variable with array type needs an
      explicit size or an initializer
    char xyz [] {"xyz"};
         ^
examples.cpp:163:16: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    char xyz [] {"xyz"};
               ^
               ;
examples.cpp:164:10: error: definition of variable with array type needs an
      explicit size or an initializer
    char xyz2 [] {"akj"};
         ^
examples.cpp:164:17: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    char xyz2 [] {"akj"};
                ^
                ;
examples.cpp:166:10: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (auto i: xyz2)
         ^
examples.cpp:166:16: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (auto i: xyz2)
               ^
examples.cpp:171:10: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (auto i: xyx)
         ^
examples.cpp:171:16: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (auto i: xyx)
               ^
examples.cpp:178:10: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (auto i: xyx2)
         ^
examples.cpp:178:16: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (auto i: xyx2)
               ^
examples.cpp:184:10: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (auto i: s1)
         ^
examples.cpp:184:16: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (auto i: s1)
               ^
examples.cpp:190:14: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    string s3 {"abcd"};
             ^
             ;
examples.cpp:191:14: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    string s4 {"abcde", 2};
             ^
             ;
examples.cpp:192:14: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    string s5 {3, 'X'};
             ^
             ;
examples.cpp:200:15: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    string pt1 {"xyx"};
              ^
              ;
examples.cpp:201:15: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    string pt2 {" kkk"};
              ^
              ;
examples.cpp:204:10: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (auto i: sentence)
         ^
examples.cpp:204:16: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension
      [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (auto i: sentence)
               ^
14 warnings and 16 errors generated.
make: *** [examples] Error 1
```

So I tried(and I'm not sure whether this is even valid):

```
c++ examples.cpp -std=c++11
```

I got less errors but it failed anyway:

```
examples.cpp:44:23: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    long double x2 = 1'000'000;
                      ^
                      ;
examples.cpp:103:18: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
        default: "shouldn't execute";
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
examples.cpp:143:32: warning: relational comparison result unused
      [-Wunused-comparison]
    for (int i = 0, j = 100; i <= 100, j >= 0; ++i, --j)
                             ~~^~~~~~
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
```

and here's what I get when I use std=c++20:

```
error: invalid value 'c++20' in '-std=c++20'
note: use 'c++98' or 'c++03' for 'ISO C++ 1998 with amendments' standard
note: use 'gnu++98' or 'gnu++03' for 'ISO C++ 1998 with amendments and GNU
      extensions' standard
note: use 'c++11' for 'ISO C++ 2011 with amendments' standard
note: use 'gnu++11' for 'ISO C++ 2011 with amendments and GNU extensions'
      standard
note: use 'c++14' for 'ISO C++ 2014 with amendments' standard
note: use 'gnu++14' for 'ISO C++ 2014 with amendments and GNU extensions'
      standard
note: use 'c++17' for 'ISO C++ 2017 with amendments' standard
note: use 'gnu++17' for 'ISO C++ 2017 with amendments and GNU extensions'
      standard
note: use 'c++2a' for 'Working draft for ISO C++ 2020' standard
note: use 'gnu++2a' for 'Working draft for ISO C++ 2020 with GNU extensions'
      standard
```

What is the proper way of running c++ files in the terminal and in general? why is it failing in the terminal and the same code runs perfectly fine in the IDE? I'm sorry if this sounds stupid and thanks in advance.

Comment: Try compiling with `-std=c++20`

Comment: @JCWasmx86 I already tried and it fails, I'll edit to show what I get

Comment: Try using `c++2a`

Comment: I get 2 other warnings

Comment: Writing a huge pile of code first, and only then seeing if it compiles, is a recipe for a guaranteed failure, and endless confusion. This is not how experienced C++ developers write code. They write only a small amount of code at a time, then compile and ***test*** it to see if it works, then write some more, and so on. This way they're not overwhelmed with digging through a mountain of errors. You should start over, from scratch, and take a small, incremental approach to writing your program.

Comment: `default: "shouldn't execute";` doesn't even make sense. `for (int i = 0, j = 100; i <= 100, j >= 0; ++i, --j)` change it to `for (int i = 0, j = 100; i <= 100&& j >= 0; ++i, --j)`

Comment: I was able to compile with `g++ -std=c++17`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I totally agree, this is just a scratch file, it's not some useful code as you can see, however, as I previously indicated in the question, it runs perfectly fine in the IDE, why it doesn't run in the terminal, on the same machine that resulted in a clean run? Which part am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Waqar I get 2 warnings using `-std=c++17`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik _"They write only a small amount of code at a time, then compile and test it to see if it works"_ -- this doesn't ring true for me at all. I work on a large project which has long compile times. An experienced C++ developer should have a good inkling of whether the code will compile (though maybe not behave correctly), and so it's not uncommon to write an entire feature with tests and compile at the end. Not saying I disagree with the recommendation for a newer developer though

Comment: @sK500 see my answer

Comment: @Human-Compiler I'm more inclined to your opinion, I don't think it's a problem of testing smaller chunks because I already did that for every function separately, it's something else.

Comment: @sK500 You just use different configuration in IDE and in terminal, it's the only "wrong" part. IDE either uses a build system like make/CMake or it has it's own system where you can click away different options. You need to replicate that configuration in terminal. The obvious thing is that you need at least C++14 for `'` separator in integer literal (I don't see a reason to need higher standard after brief look, but it's possible). Then you need to match warning flags between IDE and terminal. And of course make sure you are using same compiler.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen whatever I do, I'm getting wither warnings or errors whether(c++ 11, 17, 20 ...) and it runs perfectly fine in the IDE which is surprising specially I checked the settings and I did not find anything that looks suspicious / any different but I may have overlooked something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do with your code, but you need to compile with C++17:

```
g++ -std=c++17 examples.cpp -o examples
./examples
```

> I get 2 other warnings

One warning is here:

```
        default: "shouldn't execute";
```

You probably meant:

```
default:
   cout << "shouldn't execute";
   break;
```

Second warning is here:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 100; i <= 100, j >= 0; ++i, --j)
```

`i <= 100` is left unused and only `j >= 0` will be considered because of the comma operator. You need to write:

```
i <= 100 && j >= 0
```

Comment: Well, his GCC does not support C++20, which has confused him at the end of his issue :)

Comment: thanks for answering, why `i <= 100 is left unused` and it's being incremented? and why are you using `examples.cpp.cpp` while the file name is just `examples.cpp`?

Comment: @Waqar that's what I thought

Comment: Yes, it's incrementing. As for why it's unused, read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Comment: I'll check the link, thanks. Another thing: why the same warnings do not show up in the IDE?

Comment: Maybe because the warning flags are not enabled there or maybe it is showing the warnings in some separate window that is not visible. Generally you should enable `-Wall -Wpedantic - Wextra` to get all the warnings and fix them as soon as possible.